# How to find other than current value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, how can I get data from a column other than specified data.
For example, I have a column with data "MySQL,Server,Database" in single row.

Now I want to find if there is any other value than MySQL in that column.

I tried by using Not Like but didn't succeed.

For example TableA :

```
id |   Code   
---+---------------------------
 1 |   mysql,sqlserver,database    
 2 |   mysql    
 3 |   sqlserver,database 
 4 |   mysql,mysql
```

Here, I want to find if the column has data other than "mysql" or not, like id:1 has data other than "mysql" but id:2 have "mysql" but not other than "mysql". 
Finally if I want to return the null or blank value if there no any data other than "mysql".

Code I used so far :

```
select code from tableA where code not like '%mysql%'
```

Comment: `code != 'mysql'`

Comment: Is the correct answer for `Id=4` true or false?

Comment: Also, check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: SQL Server has data types **designed** for holding multiple values. The most obvious ones you'll see are *tables*. Storing multiple values as a comma-separated string is a *bad* idea. If you properly modelled this by storing *one code per row* then this turns into a simple relational division problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you can provide some data and some code.  This works (as far as I understand the question):

```
CREATE TABLE #x (object_type varchar(50))
INSERT #x (object_type) VALUES ('MySQL'), ('Server'), ('Database')
SELECT * FROM #x WHERE object_type <> 'MySQL'
```

Base on the updated question, I think you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE #x (id int identity(1, 1), code varchar(50))
INSERT #x (code) VALUES ('mysql,sqlserver,database'), ('mysql'), ('sqlserver,database'), ('mysql,mysql')

SELECT *
FROM #x
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM #x  
        CROSS APPLY string_split(code, ',')
    WHERE value <> 'mysql'
)
```

However, as @Eric Brandt asked above, it's not clear whether you want to select row id = 4.

Comment: My column has data in one column (mysql,server,database) and i need to find if there is other data than mysql in that column . Its not 3 rows of data, its in a single row in one column

Comment: @DaleBurrell Please find the updated question above with example.

Answer (score 0):

Note `STRING_SPLIT` is only available for `SQL Server 2016` or later. if you are using a earlier version, do a search, there are lots of similar implementation

```
declare @table table
(
    id  int identity,
    Code    varchar(30)
)

insert into @table select 'mysql,sqlserver,database'
insert into @table select 'mysql'
insert into @table select 'sqlserver,database'
insert into @table select 'mysql,mysql'
insert into @table select ''
insert into @table select NULL
select  *
from    @table t
where   t.Code  is null
or  exists  
    (
        select  *
        from    string_split(t.Code, ',')
        where   value   <> 'mysql'
    )

/*  RESULT
    1   mysql,sqlserver,database
    3   sqlserver,database
    5   
    6   NULL
*/
```

Comment: The OP requested rows that have entries other than "MySQL", e.g. row `1` (and `3`), not rows that do not contain "MySQL". (They have yet to specify whether row `4` is to be included or excluded.)

Comment: Updated the query